# Mantener una sesion activa con front-end angularjs y backend php

Tags: php, angularjs, session

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion SPA en angularjs y el backend esta hecho con PHP.  El problema esta cuando un usuario no usa la aplicacion por algun tiempo y la sesion caduca. En ese momento se hace la peticion al backend y como estoy guardando algunos datos en la sesion de php, pareciera que se queda procesando eternamente.

Como hago para evitar esto?

Comment: Tengo la aplicacion alojada en un servidor virtual y por  eso no tengo acceso al archivo php.ini para modificar los parametros de la sesion

Comment: Me parece que estás planteando 2 preguntas en 1: por un lado, cómo mantener/renovar la sesión; pero además, estás planteando que el script PHP no responde... ¿Podrías especificar más en concreto cuál es la pegunta, y cuál es el objetivo que estás intentando obtener? Además, si el problema es sobre un código que no responde, por favor agrega las partes relevantes de tu código en la pregunta. Encontrarás el enlace a [edit] al pie de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Una solucion seria q enviaras un ajax al servidor renovando la sesion cada cierto tiempo

UPDATE 1:

```
Puedes hacer algo como esto en tu .js

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(sessionRenew, X);//Se ejecutara sessionRenew cada X tiempo dado en milisegundos
});
function sessionRenew(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/file', // Archivo donde renueva sus datos
        type: 'POST', //Tipo de envio al server
        data: {session: 'renew'}, //Parametros que envias
        success: function(resp){
            doSomething(); //Que hacer despues de una respuesta
            console.log('Session renew' + resp); //Comunicar a la consola JS el msg
        }
    })//Aqui en adelante puedes ver la documentacion de jQuery Ajax, es teoricamente un equivalente a lo anterior
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
}
```

Comment: @JuankGlezz Yo creo q si da una solucion, ya que resuelve la pregunta principal, ¿Como evitar que una sesion caduque? lo cual se puede evitar si realizas una peticion constante al servidor y renuevas la sesion.

Comment: Hola @FrankLeal, aunque sea respuesta, es más una aproximación que una respuesta concreta y concisa. No obstante, puedes editarla y añadir código de ejemplo así como enlaces para completarla. Tienes una guía sobre [answer], échale un vistazo cuando tengas tiempo. Gracias por colaborar con SOes.